# Why does the iconComponent used with Select show on the line after the input?

Tags: material-ui

It should replace the default caret but while the caret isn't shown my icon (using a custom in-house component that renders and SVG image) ends up on the line after the input, overlapped with the hint text.

My code:

```
  <MuiSelect
    value={value}
    classes={{
      disabled: classes.disabled,
    }}
    IconComponent={() => (
      <Icon name="keyboard_arrow_down" size="small" />
    )}
    input={<TextField optional={optional} label={label} hintText={hintText} />}
    disabled={disabled}
    onChange={props.handleChange}
    {...others}>
    {children}
  </MuiSelect>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the icon passed in doesn't have the same css applied to it that the default icon does...

I used the following and it seems to work OK...

```
iconStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '0',
    right: '0',
    display: 'inline-block',
    color: '#c0c0c0',
    width: '24px',
    height: '24px',
    pointerEvents: 'none'
}

<Select 
  IconComponent={() => <YourSelectIcon className={classes.iconStyle} />}
>
  items here...
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's some CSS added via a class, adding the same CSS to my custom component did the trick.